# How to specify the axes of a tensor in julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I am using Julia 1.9.0.

`H` is a multidimensional array. We assume the size is `I1×I2×...×ID` where `D` is called the order of `H`.

For a given tuple `(j1,j2,...,jD)`, I want to define `H` such that
`H[i1,i2,...,id] = 1` if `j1≦i1` and `j2≦i2` and ... and `jD≦iD` otherwise `0`.

I wrote an example code for D=2.

```
function main(tensor_size, jdx::CartesianIndex)
    H = zeros(tensor_size)
    H[jdx[1]:end,jdx[2]:end] .= 1
    return H
end

tensor_size = (4,4)
jdx = CartesianIndex(3,2)
main(tensor_size, jdx)

# 4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
# 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
# 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
# 0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
# 0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

How should I provide the code for general `D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
julia> quadrant(sz, corner) = 
  [ifelse(all(Tuple(idx) .>= corner), 1, 0) for idx in CartesianIndices(sz)]
lowerright (generic function with 1 method)

julia> H = quadrant((4,4),(3,2))
4×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  1  1  1
 0  1  1  1
```

You may also look at:

```
function quadrant(::Type{T}, sz, corner) where {T<:Number}
    H = zeros(T, sz)
    H[(:).(corner, sz)...] .= one(T)
    return H
end
quadrant(sz, corner) = quadrant(Float64, sz, corner)
```

which gives:

```
julia> quadrant(Int, (4,4), (3,2))
4×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  1  1  1
 0  1  1  1
```

Comment: The first function can also be made into `quadrant(::Type{T}, sz, corner) where {T <: Number} = [T(all(Tuple(idx) .>= corner)) for idx in CartesianIndices(sz)]`